# How to update same name multiple data in database?

Tags: php

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="link_name[]" value="xyz" />
            <input type="text" name="link_name[]" value="abc" />
            <input type="text" name="link_name[]" value="qwe" />
            <input type="text" name="link_name[]" value="asd" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>            
        </fieldset>    
    </form>
```

I want to update any of single data in database.. eg.. if i have to update first text field value like xxx.. then how can i update it using post method.. I want to update not insert so please help me.. give some demo or hint..

if i use like

```
if(isset($_post['submit']))
{
  $link_name=$_POST['link_name'];
  mysql_query("update tbl set link_name='$link_name' where id='$id'");
}
```

then it change all my record with same name.. i cant able to change any particular data.. so please give some suggestion.

I want to update any of single data in database.. eg.. if i have to update first text field value like xxx.. then how can i update it using post method.. I want to update not insert so please help me.. give some demo or hint..

Comment: where is $id defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the id of every input. You can use different aproaches. For example you can have a hidden input for every text input with the id of this row

```
<input type="text" name="link_name[]" value="xyz" />
<input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="340" />
```

And in the server you need to do a loop on the link_name array and for each element recover the id:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($link_name);$i++)
{
  $id = $_POST['ids'][$i];
   mysql_query("update tbl set link_name='$link_name' where id='$id'");
}
```

Comment: i try your code but one prob.. $link_name give Array  like this update tbl set link_name='Array' where id='7'

Comment: mysql_query("update tbl set link_name='".$link_name[$i]."' where id='$id'");

Comment: suppose we have thousands of record then it take lots of time.. for that do you have any other solution..??

Answer (score 0):

to update  a single record put a hidden field in the form that holds the id if the post to be updated and then try this

```
// update only first field
        if(isset($_post['submit']))
        {
    //var_dump($_POST['link_name']);
          $link_name=$_POST['link_name'][0];
          mysql_query("update tbl set link_name='$link_name' where id='$id'");
        }

// update all field
foreach($_POST['link_name'] as $link_name)
{
 mysql_query("update tbl set link_name='$link_name' where id='$id'");
}
```

Comment: this is update single record but if i want to update other data not [0] index data then what??